# How to get DeviceID Android?

Tags: java, android

How to get **unically** Deviceid in Android?
For smartphones and tablets.
As I understood it may be not unically?

Will this code works?
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Comment: A related question with a well-written answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id/2853253#2853253

Comment: Quote: "Telephony-based ID won't be there on tablet devices, neh?"

Comment: You can use the AndroidID, but if a phone is rooted, it will be null. In my experience, I've used a bunch of these at once.  Checked to see if androidID was null, if so, went with telephony id or mac address.

Comment: Please refer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id

Comment: @jbenowitz I use a rooted SGS2 for development, the adMob SDK did show me an ID in the LogCat, however I have no clue where it came from

Comment: Well, try the AndroidID way.  I could be wrong.  I've also done what is detailed here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5626208/811282   Not sure if mocking this will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an easy way of getting the device Id that will also work on tablets

```
public class DeviceHelper {

private static String sID = null;
private static final String INSTALLATION = "INSTALLATION";

public synchronized static String getDeviceId(final Context context) {
    if (sID == null) {
        File installation = new File(context.getFilesDir(), INSTALLATION);
        try {
            if (!installation.exists()){
                writeInstallationFile(context,installation);
            }
            sID = readInstallationFile(installation);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    return sID;
}

private static String readInstallationFile(File installation) throws IOException {
    RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(installation, "r");
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) f.length()];
    f.readFully(bytes);
    f.close();
    return new String(bytes);
}

private static void writeInstallationFile(final Context context,File installation) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(installation);
    StringBuffer buf=new StringBuffer();
    buf.append(Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID));
    buf.append("-");
    buf.append(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    out.write(buf.toString().getBytes());
    out.close();
}

}
```

Comment: CAUTION!!!! According to the documentations, The value of `ANDROID_ID` may change if a factory reset is performed on the device

Answer (score 0):

Simplest code to get Unique ID of an android device: (This works on tablets also.)

```
    String deviceId = Secure.getString(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    Log.d("Device ID",deviceId);
```

Comment: It's known to be null sometimes

Comment: CAUTION!!!! According to the documentations, The value of `ANDROID_ID` may change if a factory reset is performed on the device

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```
final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) c
        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
Log.w("ID", tm.getDeviceId());
```